# Why do the space time get curved around a massive object?What problems do we face if we do not consider the space time to be curved?

Tags: general-relativity

As far as I have the knowledge of GTR that a mass bends the space time around it.But why does this bend occur?The example from real life that when a mass is placed on a net then the net bends but it us very difficult for me to visualise the situation of bending of spacetime due to a mass.What is actually happening?What is the physical basis behind this bend?I want to say that the books which I have studied till now just say that the space time "just bends" around an object and even my teacher told me that it just bends without any explanation so I just want to know the reason for the occurrence of this bend.What is the need for spacetime to bend around an object?What physical problem we can encounter if we do not the bending of space time.

Comment: As it stands, I can't quite understand what you are trying to ask. This may indicate that this question is too unclear/does not contain enough information to be useful to this site. Please try to improve the question by adding more information or rephrasing some things. If this is not done, the question is likely to be closed.

Comment: The answer to this question can be understood by reading the currently accepted quantum theory of gravity. And to do that... you have to wait because we don't have one. Although we have candidates such as String Theory, though no candidate is an actual accepted theory of reality since we haven't figured out a way to practically measure their claims. For now we just have to accept that "it happens", and in such a manner as described by Einstein/Hilbert equation. The "how" will remain a mystery for some time.

Comment: Try to ask yourself a different question - why do two opposite charges repulse each other? There is an answer which describes the force by means of a photon "bumping" into the charge, but then again you could ask why the photon gets sent out. And there would be another "why" question about an explanation of that. These "why" questions have no ending - they only reveal deeper and deeper structure. There most probably is deeper structure even here, but for now we don't know it. So we provide no explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As photons have energy, gravity affects light rays, turning their path from straight to curved, and changing their energy (frequency/color).

In classical relativity light always travels in a straight zero-lenght line, with phase speed = $c$.
If you include gravity in your relativistic model you this is not true anymore. As this is an important property of the model that helps verifying that the theory is sound, instead of using a model where you cannot trust light going straight, you change your definition of "straight" so that it stays coherent with the fact that light moves in a straight line. That's where the "curved spacetime" comes from.

So the logical process is not:

- I observe some strange physical phenomenon from which I conclude that the spacetime is curved
- I know that light goes straight, but the space is curved
- the light curves

but instead:

- I observe light going around big masses
- But I know that light goes in straight lines
- I either have to change the idea that light goes in straight lines, or that the space is plain
- I prefer keeping in my model the property that light goes in straight lines, and from my biased point of view the space is curved

This is consistent to the idea beyond special relativity, in which Einstein decided that instead of preserving the rule that speed adds up while changing the system of reference preferred keeping the rule that the speed of light is the same in all (inertial) system of reference.

Comment: `As photons have energy, gravity affects light rays` - actually energy is not needed here, gravity affects any geodesics. The energy is needed for light rays to affect gravity (though this is a very small effect). And for SR, the rule that speed adds up could not be preserved anyway, but in GR we can treat gravitational field non-goemetrically - then the light would go not in straight lines.

Comment: @firtree your comment is biased by the fact that you think of gravity in a setting in which it is not a force between bodies, but an effect of energy on space. If you start from your high school knowledge that $F= G\frac{M\cdot m}{r^2}$ and add in the equation $E=m\cdot c^2$ it is clear as the sun that you can think of gravity as a force that attracts entities with mass/energy to each other. Of course using this newtonian formalism makes solving equations harder, but this is nevertheless what is observed.

Comment: Actually what is observed is twice the effect calculated by Newtonian formalism, and the equation $E=mc^2$ is plain wrong. I use classical physics analogies to explain something when they are applicable, but I highly object using them when they are not. That would be lying to the student and that would backfire at some point later.

Comment: @firtree Of course the quantitative results would be wrong if you use the classical mechanics, but I never tried to formulate a quantitative version of the general relativity using newton equations. My reasoning is that we observe that gravity pull things together, we observe that it effect also light rays, we decide that we want to keep light rays going straight no matter what, we decide to change the definition of straight line. And *this is not wrong*, and actually cleared the OP of his doubt. Hope my point is clear

Comment: The most part of your answer is not wrong, I agree. But the first sentence is wrong, and even your defence of it is wrong. I wanted to point out just that.

Comment: @firtree if you don't use a curved space you have to put into your model gravitational interaction among entities which increases with their energy. Or not? The fact that trajectories of light rays do not depend on their energy and remains the same for the limit of photon energy going to zero has nothing to do with that. Actually, this happens even in classical gravitation: the trajectories of orbiting bodies on a statical gravitational field do not depend on the mass of the exploring mass. Why you want to make it sound complicated?

Comment: Now you have a flaw in your reasoning: you start with the idea that the space is not curved, and come to the idea that the space is curved :-) Please be consistent. This is not complicated, of course, but it takes some exactness.

Comment: @firtree If you read carefully, it is consistent. My point is that you can explain gravity with either attractive force between entities or curved space, and curved space is what has been chosen by general relativity because it is leads to a simpler formalism and easier calculations. I consider your last comment to be trolling, thus I will stop the conversation here. If you still have points to make, please write your own explanation and downvote this one.

Comment: It's a pity that my point escaped your attention.

Answer (score 1):

In general relativity the fundamental equation is roughly $$\textrm{Curvature} = \textrm{Matter content}$$ .In the context of general relativity it does not make sense to ask "why" matter curves spacetime, because this is *the* most basic assumption in the theory.

It makes more sense to ask why one would try to construct a theory where gravitation is a geometric theory. The answer to that question is the equivalence of gravitational and inertial mass: the dynamics of a particle in gravitational fields are independent of the particle mass.

Accepting that the equation for gravitation should be something like $$\textrm{Geometry} = \textrm{Matter}$$ one can make physical arguments for why he left-hand side should be (a particular measure of) curvature: the curvature has the the right number of derivatives (two), it is zero for the spacetime of special relativity, it has the correct number of components, and using the correct measure of curvature, conservation of energy is automatic.